# How can I develop Cubicweb 4 Frontend?

Tags: python

I've been reading about Cubicweb 4, which is starting to focus on the server, RQL and REST services, to build an application in some JavaScript or Typescript client. Where can I learn more on how to build an application using Cubicweb 4 and ReactJS or some other client?

I would like to understand if ReactJS is the preferred or must client framework.

I would like to understand if there's some automatic generation of the JS client views, similar to the current Primary view in Cubicweb 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CubicWeb 4 is out and the documentation needs an update. Here is some quick answer to keep you waiting.

ReactJS is the JS framework most used by CubicWeb developers, but there are projects that use AngularJS. The CubicWeb libraries used to develop with AngularJS are less advanced at this point (to help HTML form generation for example).

Regarding the automatic generation of client views, there are two main options that complement each other and illustrates the focus that CubicWeb puts on separating data and user interfaces to connect them using well-defined ontologies.

The first one is to use a very generic admin interface that you can connect to any running instance that has the [api cube](https://forge.extranet.logilab.fr/cubicweb/cubes/api/) installed. This admin user interface is based on the [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) library from Marmelab.

The cubicweb-react-admin client will use the routes from the API cube to get the schema then generate on the fly the user interface to navigate through all the data, both to display and edit it.

That is what CubicWeb was doing by default in CubicWeb 3 and you can have this behaviour on the server side with CubicWeb 4 if you add the [web cube](https://forge.extranet.logilab.fr/cubicweb/cubes/web) to your instance (but the goal is to move away from server-side rendering).

The second option is to use the [cubicweb js libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cubicweb) that you can find in the npmjs directory. For example there is a library called @cubicweb/react-form-utils that helps generating react user interfaces and can be combined with the other libraries you will chose to render the elements and manage the forms (for example cubicweb + bootstrap + react-hook-form + yup).

I hope this helps. More information will be added to the blog and the documentation at https://www.cubicweb.org